# I have VBA code that requires pop up boxes to work, can I automate this

Tags: excel, vba

Below is some code that splits a long column in excel into smaller columns.

This works by clicking into the module, pressing F5 and entering ranges, an output starting point and a cell range to signal the number of entries in each column.

Is there anyway I can automate this, for example, if I have a column with 1:30 starting in A1, I always want to use this range, the output cell I would like is H25 and I would like the number of entries based on whatever I input into say cell G6.

```
Sub SplitColumn()
    'Updateby20141106
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim InputRng As Range
    Dim OutRng As Range
    Dim xRow As Integer
    Dim xCol As Integer
    Dim xArr As Variant
    xTitleId     = "KutoolsforExcel"
    Set InputRng = Application.Selection
    Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type: = 8)
    xRow         = Application.InputBox("Rows :", xTitleId)
    Set OutRng   = Application.InputBox("Out put to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type: = 8)
    Set InputRng = InputRng.Columns(1)
    xCol         = InputRng.Cells.Count / xRow
    ReDim xArr(1 To xRow, 1 To xCol + 1)
    For i = 0 To InputRng.Cells.Count - 1
        xValue = InputRng.Cells(i + 1)
        iRow = i Mod xRow
        iCol = VBA.Int(i / xRow)
        xArr(iRow + 1, iCol + 1) = xValue
    Next
    OutRng.Resize(UBound(xArr, 1), UBound(xArr, 2)).Value = xArr
End Sub
```

Comment: are you talking about removing user input, and just hardcoding what used to be the user input?

Comment: Change the values of rng,inputrng, outrng to your hard-coded ranges

Comment: @ArcherBird if you could make this an answer and spell it out a bit more that would be great!!!

Comment: Is that number of rows? _" I would like the number of entries based"_

Comment: @Wizhi say I have a list of numbers in Column A, starting in A1 with a 1 and finishing in A30 with a 30. I would like this code to split this long column into 10 smaller columns all with 3 entries in. When i use the code manually it asks how many rows (i.e. the number of entries in each subcolumn), i simply enter a cell as in cell G4 say is a 3 which signals the number of rows I would like.

Comment: It also asks where I would like this new table, I would like this to always be in H22

Comment: The only variable I need is the number of columns it is split into and this is based on the value of a cell

Comment: You have the modification below with explanations :). Hopefully it do what you wish. I did some modifications if you don't have any value in G4, so you don't get error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want something like this...

So what do we need to change?... By press F8 in the VBA window we can step by step see what each line do..

1- This part defines your range to split, so we replace it:

```
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type: = 8)
```

To a hard coded range:

```
Set InputRng = Range("A1:A30")
```

2- Next part defines which cell to output the result:

```
Set OutRng   = Application.InputBox("Out put to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type: = 8)
```

We hardcode this to cell range.

```
Set OutRng = Range("H22")
```

3- Last part to edit is this:

```
xRow         = Application.InputBox("Rows :", xTitleId)
```

Will take the value you have in `G4`

```
xRow = Cells(4, 7).Value
```

The final modifications can be more tricky to spot. The selection is hardcoded, so we don't need it. Therefore we can remove line `Set InputRng = Application.Selection`

If we don't have any value in `G4` we will get a division by 0 error. We therefore create an IF statement that will show a message box "No Value in G4" if cell G4 is 0.

**Modified code:**

```
Sub SplitColumn()
    'Updateby20141106
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim InputRng As Range
    Dim OutRng As Range
    Dim xRow As Integer
    Dim xCol As Integer
    Dim xArr As Variant
    xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
    Set InputRng = Range("A1:A30")
    xRow = Cells(4, 7).Value
    Set OutRng = Range("H22")
    If xRow = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No value in G4"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set InputRng = InputRng.Columns(1)
        xCol = InputRng.Cells.Count / xRow
        ReDim xArr(1 To xRow, 1 To xCol + 1)
            For i = 0 To InputRng.Cells.Count - 1
                xValue = InputRng.Cells(i + 1)
                iRow = i Mod xRow
                iCol = VBA.Int(i / xRow)
                xArr(iRow + 1, iCol + 1) = xValue
            Next i
        OutRng.Resize(UBound(xArr, 1), UBound(xArr, 2)).Value = xArr
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Arguably the user inputs would be refactored into parameters instead of hard-coded into the logic itself. But, good enough.

Comment: Thank you!! I can agree with you on that point. I think the most important lesson is to take care of the potential error that occurs when you don't have any value in the cell and will be a result of modifying the code. I think it's horrible that people just set `On Error` and hide the problem instead of deal/try to solve it :)